# Save only the current time in a column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table and I want to save in my column `hora_inicio_uso` only the current time

```
CREATE TABLE prestamo_usuarios(
    matricula_alumno VARCHAR(255),
    id_equipo INT,
    fecha_prestamo DATE,
    fecha_devolucion DATE,
    hora_inicio_uso DATE,
    hora_fin_uso DATE,
    id_prestamo INT
);
```

I insert data into this table through a procedure

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE RealizarPrestamoEquipo (IN matricula_param VARCHAR(255), IN equipo_param INT(11), IN id_prestamo_param INT(11))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO prestamo_usuarios 
        (matricula_alumno, id_equipo, fecha_prestamo, hora_inicio_uso, id_prestamo) 
    VALUES 
        (matricula_param, equipo_param, CURDATE(), CURTIME(), id_prestamo_param);
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to solve this with the `CURTIME()` function, but this only saves the current date where I should keep the time, some idea of how I can do this?

Comment: `hora_inicio_uso` is defined as `DATE` type. Define it as `Time` instead

Comment: But save yourself from future troubles by simply defining a single `DATETIME` column instead and store `NOW()` instead of two separate columns for date and time

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya How can I edit only the time?

Comment: Single DATETIME column is always better. If you really want two columns, you can create a VIEW from the parent table which has date and time.

Comment: *How can I edit only the time?* first define the column's data type as `Time` (not Date as you currently have it) but at some point in the future you may wish you had both date and time as a single value.